# How to get merge request labels in gitlab pipeline

Tags: git, gitlab

I am trying to add git version tags based on labels attached with a merge request, how can I get them in pipelines scripts?

Comment: What do you mean by "git version tags"? Actually creating a git tag with name formed from MR labels?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily there is a variable just for that in [Predefined environment variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html)

See `CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS`

> Comma-separated label names of the merge request if the pipelines are for merge requests. Available only if only: [merge_requests] is used and the merge request is created.

As mentioned you will need to define for your job in `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
only:
  - merge_requests
```